# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.jawaher.ff.model.UserData.getErrorCode()' on a null object

Tags: android-studio

this error always come to my on crashlytics dashboard and I need help

here is the error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.jawaher.ff.model.UserData.getErrorCode()' on a null object reference
       at com.jawaher.ff.fragments.HomeFragment$11.onResponse(HomeFragment.java:184)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

here is the part of the code that crash on

```
 private void getLatestQuiz(){

        Call<FetchQuiz> fetchLatestQuizCall = ApiController.getInstance().getApi().getLatestQuiz();

        fetchLatestQuizCall.enqueue(new Callback<FetchQuiz>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FetchQuiz> call, Response<FetchQuiz> response) {

                FetchQuiz result = response.body();
                assert result != null;
                int errorCode = result.getErrorCode();
                String message = result.getMessage();
                Log.d(TAG,"fetchLatestQuizCall     Response =  errorCode :- "+errorCode+"  message :- "+message);

                if (errorCode==0 && message.equals("Data fetched")){
                    List<Quiz> quizList = result.getQuizList();
                    setLatestQuizRecyclerview(quizList,getContextNullSafety());
                }
                else {
                    binding.textLatestQuiz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    binding.textMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FetchQuiz> call, Throwable t) {
                binding.textLatestQuiz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                binding.textMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d(TAG,"fetchLatestQuizCall  failure"+t.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.d(Constants.ERROR_TAG,"fetchLatestQuizCall Failure = "+t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });


    }
```

I tried to add

```
assert result != null;
```

but the crash appeared again please help I don't know what is wrong with the code and how to fix it

Comment: I can't tell if `assert`s are disabled, but if `Response` can return `null` from `.body()`, you'll need to code that as a possibility. If it shouldn't, then the bug is more likely in that class.

Comment: Look at the documentation (or source code if it's a custom class) for the `Response` class, it might be correct for it to return `null` for `.body()` (e.g. Retrofit2 has a flag `.isSuccessful()` that must be `true` for `.body()` to return a valid object). If that's the case, then you must decide what that means to your code. Maybe treat it like `errorCode != 0`, maybe there's a way to get information about why it's not successful (e.g. `.errorBody()` in Retrofit2).